# Passing an array from html form to gs

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, forms

I'm using Google App Script.

I've created drop down boxes from values in a Google Sheet. My intent is to collect the selectedIndex(es) in an array, send them to the back end as parameters, and have them output a value from the same Google Sheet based on an argument.

I'm able to successfully pass the array of selected indexes of the drop down boxes from the html form to the back end (code.gs), but when I try to get the value of a cell in Google Sheets using getRange & selectedindexes, I always get these errors:

> console.log - Uncaught  at calculateCL (Code:22)
>
> Logger.log - is able to log the value of the cell but when I "return PTvalue", the front end logs it as undefined.

Please help!

**page.html**

```
//gets selected index from dropdown
    var CountryIndex = document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex;
    var CUTypeIndex = document.getElementById("ListCUTyp").selectedIndex;

//pushes indices into array 
    formArray = [];
    formArray.push(CountryIndex);
    formArray.push(CUTypeIndex);

//array sent to back end within function calculateCL
//on success of calculateCL, run function CLOutput
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(CLOutput()).calculateCL(formArray)

//outputs value from GS
    function CLOutput(PTvalue){
                console.log(PTvalue);
                document.getElementById("ListPT").value = PTvalue;
            }
```

**code.gs**

```
//gets value of cell based on selected index array
        function calculateCL(formArray) {
          var PTvalue = sheet.getRange(2+formArray[0], 2+formArray[1]).getValue();
          Logger.log(PTvalue);
          return PTvalue;
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771993/7215091) .  It's hard to determine what your code is doing.  There are no script tags and no html to see where the functions are called from.  We have no crystal balls.  You have to explain clearly what you problem is.  Check out these resources [ask] [mcve]

Comment: Clearly formArray is undefined.  Perhaps because of this call `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(CLOutput()).calculateCL()` no parameter was passed.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I was able to pass the parameter in the line above it: google.script.run.calculateCL(formArray)

Logger.log(PTvalue) - is able to log the value of the cell but when I "return PTvalue" the front end logs it as undefined.

Comment: Why do you think the first call influences the second? You execute the first call with a parameter, and discard any return value from the server-side function since you bind no success handler for that call. Then for the call that has a success handler, you pass no parameter. Re-read the entire guide on communication: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Comment: Thanks tehhowch! That helped. Will read now.

Comment: Review also the difference between `foo` and `foo()`, given the code `function foo() {}` (hint: what is the output of `typeof` for each case?)

Answer (score 0):

Your `calculateCL` has parameter but seems like you are using it without a parameter inside.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(CLOutput()).`calculateCL()`
```

Take a look at your function:

```
function calculateCL(formArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
 google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(CLOutput())
.calculateCL(formArray);
```

This is a correct form:

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(CLOutput)
.calculateCL(formArray)

 function CLOutput(PTvalue){
   console.log(PTvalue);
   document.getElementById("ListPT").value = PTvalue;
 }
```

This is also correct

```
 google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(function(PTValue){
    console.log(PTvalue);
    document.getElementById("ListPT").value = PTvalue;
})
.calculateCL(formArray)
```