# I am trying to pass a variable from my Google Script through to HtmlOutputFromFile

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am trying to create an input box with a drop down list, where that list is based on a 2D array pulled from a Spreadsheet.

My research so far has told me that if i store the HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile in a variable that I can then "set properties" of that variable that will then get passed to the html. (i saw this used specifically with HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile)

```
//google script code
function selectMonth(){
  var monthTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var LR = monthTab.getRange("B1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()
  var sNamesArray = monthTab.getRange(1,2,LR,2).getValues()

  var monthBox = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Month Box')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(50);

//i believe the error to be occurring on this line
  monthBox.mList = sNamesArray

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(monthBox, 'Student Name List');
};

<!--html code-->
<select id="tabMonth">
  <option disabled selected>Select Month</option>
  <?for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){ ?>
    <option value=<?mList[i][1]?>><?mList[i][0]?></option>
  <?}?>
</select>
```

but every time i try and run the code i get the error:
"Object does not allow properties to be added or changed."

based upon what i can tell the error is occurring on the line indicated above

Comment: From JavaScript you can call selectMonth() with google.script.run and return the array to withSuccessHandler. The handler can send it to a function name or handle it via an anonymous function.

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771993/7215091).  I think it's really close to what you want.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper. But i am really trying to nail down this particular technique here is the example that i am basing my question from. [this video](youtube.com/watch?v=f9dqsHDrQCc)

Comment: Does the file month box.html? have this code in it? `<select id="tabMonth">
  <option disabled selected>Select Month</option>
  <?for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){ ?>
    <option value=<?mList[i][1]?>><?mList[i][0]?></option>
  <?}?>
</select>`

Comment: @Cooper yes. That code is in my Month Box.html file.

Comment: Then this line `HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Month Box')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(50);` requires an evaluate().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Attempting to modify the `HtmlOutput` object instead of modifying `HtmlTemplate` object.

#### Solution:

- Only  the html template can be modified with variables. Modify the `template` and evaluate it to return `HtmlOutput`

#### Snippet:

```
var monthBox = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Month Box');//Type: HtmlTemplate
monthBox.mList = sNamesArray;

monthBox = monthBox.evaluate()    //Type: HtmlOutput after evaluation
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(50);

monthbox = monthbox.getContent();
```

#### References:

- [HtmlTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template)
- [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my issue! All I had to do was change remove "Html" from "createHtmlTemplateFromFile" for some reason it would not accept it as is. Thank you again.