# createHtmlTemplateFromFile not found in HtmlService when trying to pass a variable from my Google Script to HtmlOutputFromFile

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I tried solution at [I am trying to pass a variable from my Google Script through to HtmlOutputFromFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57238218/i-am-trying-to-pass-a-variable-from-my-google-script-through-to-htmloutputfromfi), but can't get it working. I get error (translated from Dutch): "TypeError: Can't find function createHtmlTemplateFromFile  in object HtmlService.

```js
function fncOpenMyDialog() {
  //Open a dialog
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlTemplateFromFile('DropDown_NewCompetitionFile');
  htmlDlg.myVar = "November";
  
  htmlDlg = htmlDlg.evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(150);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(htmlDlg, 'A Title Goes Here');
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <select name="nameYouWant">
  <option value="something">Text</option>
  <option value="anything">Drop Down Selection</option>
  <option value="anotherthing"><?myVar?></option>
</select>

<hr/>
<ul>
  <li>This is a list.</li>
  <li>This is line two.</li>

</ul>

<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>

<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
HtmlService.createHtmlTemplateFromFile
```

with

```
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do things any way you wish but this seems a lot simpler:

```
<input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

than this:

```
<button onmouseup="closeDia()">Close</button>

<script>
  window.closeDia = function() {
    google.script.host.close();
  };
</script>
```

and I prefer to load my select options via javascript on `window.onload`

Comment: Cooper, thanks for your response. I do not understand your solution. But don't worry, I am just an amateur programmer, so it is just my lack of knowledge.  (This is for our sport club). The other solution worked, so will stick with that. Cheers!