# Passing 2 parameters to .withSuccessHandler()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I've the below code, that read the data in 2 sheets, `country` and `vendor` and build droupdown list for each of them.

I wanted to try comining them in a single function using something like:

```
var lists = ["country", "vendor"];
lists.forEach()
// or
// for list in lists {}
```

But stuck with the `.withSuccessHandler()`how can I pass 2 inputs to it, like `list` and `list values`?

```
<script>
  function createCountryDropdown() {
      //SUBMIT YOUR DATA RANGE FOR DROPDOWN AS THE PARAMETER
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(countryDropDown)
        .getDropdownList("country");

      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(vendorDropDown)
        .getDropdownList("vendor");
  }
  function onFailure(err) {
      alert('There was an error!' + err.message);
  }
  //POPULATE COUNTRY DROPDOWNS
  function countryDropDown(values) { //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391195
    var list = document.getElementById('country');   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
     // console.log(value[i])
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text = values[i];
      list.appendChild(option);
    }
  }

    //POPULATE Vendor DROPDOWNS
  function vendorDropDown(values) { //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391195
    var list = document.getElementById('vendor');   
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
     // console.log(value[i])
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text = values[i];
      list.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help?

Comment: Maybe you want the [`withUserObject(object)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withuserobjectobject) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

You want to combine 2 `google.script.run` in a single function as follows.

```
var lists = ["country", "vendor"];
lists.forEach()
```

### Modification points:

- At first, I think that your `countryDropDown` and `vendorDropDown` can be written by one function.
- I think that the values can be retrieved by one call in Google Apps Script side using `var lists = ["country", "vendor"];`. This has already been mentioned by [Marios's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100565/7108653).

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. And, the flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Call `getDropdownLists` using `google.script.run` with `var lists = ["country", "vendor"]`.
2. At Google Apps Script side, the values are retrieved from `getDropdownList`, which is your script, and `["country", "vendor"]` using a loop.
3. Using the retrieved values from `getDropdownList`, the dropdown lists are created with `createDropDown`.

### Modified script:

#### JavaScript side:

```
// I modified this function.
function createCountryDropdown() {
  var lists = ["country", "vendor"];
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(createDropDown)
    .getDropdownLists(lists);
}

function onFailure(err) {
    alert('There was an error!' + err.message);
}

// I prepared this function.
function createDropDown(obj) { //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391195
  obj.forEach(({id, values}) => {
    var list = document.getElementById(id);
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = values[i];
      option.text = values[i];
      list.appendChild(option);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please add the following function. This function is called from Javascript side.

```
function getDropdownLists(e) {
  return e.map(f => ({id: f, values: getDropdownList(f)}));
}
```

#### Note:

Of course, you can use `google.script.run` in a loop. But I'm worry that in this case, the process cost will be higher than that of above direction.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

You can have as a function parameter an object of the form `{ country, vendor }`.

To make the code shorter, I used [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but feel free to use your own version if you want.

Similarly, the server side function `getDropdownList` needs to **return** an object of the same form to be used by the function inside `withSuccessHandler`:

```
return { country: country_values, vendor: vendor_values };
```

### Solution:

Change your **client side** function to this:

```
function createCountryDropdown() { 
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .withSuccessHandler(({ country, vendor }) => {
         var listCountry = document.getElementById('country');
         var listVendor = document.getElementById('vendor');
         
         for (var i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");     
            option.value = country[i];
            option.text = country[i];
            listCountry.appendChild(option);
         }
                            
         for (var j = 0; j < vendor.length; j++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");     
            option.value = vendor[j];
            option.text = vendor[j];
            listVendor.appendChild(option);
         }         
      })
      .getDropdownList();
}
```

Change your **server side** function to this:

```
function getDropdownList() { 
  // some code to get country_values
  // some code to get vendor_values                            
  return { country: country_values, vendor: vendor_values };
}
```

You can now delete the functions `countryDropDown` and `vendorDropDown` since they are no longer being used by `withSuccessHandler`.