# I would like to create a dropdown list in appscript but it dosent work

Tags: google-apps-script

i would like to create a dropdown list in my webapp, but it doesn't show any value. Could you help me to check? this is the code I found on another website.

I would like to set the dropdown list content as a colunm in a sheet name as "Stafflist". And the first column is different staff name, for example, Peter, Jack, Alex, David, Mary, Jane

What should I do? Thank you

here is the code(gs.code)

```
 function test() {
    try {
      var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML_Sidebar');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(output);
    }
    catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
    }
    }
  
   

     function getSheets() {
        try {
          var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZiY2abk8tZcJ_CgCELl2po1yGFnxeCO50tRtBqAN7kE").getSheetByName("Staffname");
          var names = sheets.getRange(1,1,sheets.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
          for( var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++ ) {
            names.push(sheets[i].getName());
          }
          return names;
        }
        catch(err) {
          Logger.log(err);
        }
        }
      
       function changeSheet(name) {
        try {
          var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
          var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Staffname");
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveSheet(sheet);
           }
        catch(err) {
          Logger.log(err);
         }
         }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form>
    ///html dropdown list
  <label style="font-size:16pt">Please choose your name:</label>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange="selectChange(this)">
    </select>
    <script>
      function selectChange(select) {
        google.script.run.changeSheet(select.value);
      }
      function sheetNames("Staffname") {
        var select = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = names[i];
          select.add(option);
        }
      }
      (function () { google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(sheetNames).getSheets(); }());
    </script>
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Can you show an example of the data (you can share the sheet) and what you want to see in the dropdown?

Comment: It should be `function sheetNames(names)`.

Comment: the dropdown list i want is just like [Peter, Jack, Alice,....]

Comment: Hi, by any chance does this post answer your question: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770256/dynamic-dropdown-list-in-html-form-using-google-app-script ? If not, can you provide more details on it? The code you shared does not seem to be for a Web App since it does not contain for example a `doGet()` function as mentioned on the documentation [Requirements for web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)