# Highlight Duplicate Data Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

code.gs:

```
function globalVariables(){ 
  var varArray = {
    spreadsheetId   : '1MQQK6P-4DccBogN7at5x66m7dyaDSx4FdeiSz9XhxoY', //** CHANGE !!!
    dataRage        : 'Data!A2:K',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    dataRage2       : 'Data2!A2:K',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    idRange         : 'Data!A2:A',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    idRange2         : 'Data2!A2:A',                                    //** CHANGE !!!
    lastCol         : 'K',                                            //** CHANGE !!!
    insertRange     : 'Data!A1:K1',                                   //** CHANGE !!!
    insertRange2    : 'Data2!A1:K1',                                   //** CHANGE !!!
    sheetID         : '0'                                             //** CHANGE !!! Ref:https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id
  };
  return varArray;
}
```

```
function getContactList(range){
  var list = readData(globalVariables().spreadsheetId,range);
  return list;
}
```

Javascript.html:

````
    function checkdata() {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(blurFunction).getContactList("Data!D1:D195");
  }

    function blurFunction(values) { 
      //Ref: stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391 
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
        for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){ 
          result = values[i][j]; 
          console.log(result); 
          var list = document.getElementById('contact').value; 
          if (list == result){ 
            document.getElementById("contact").style.background = "blue"; 
          }
          else { 
            document.getElementById("contact").style.background = "yellow"
          } 
        }
      }
    }

Form.html:

```html
div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="contact">Contact</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="contact"  onblur="blurFunction()">
      </div>
    </div>
````

It gives me error:

```
userCodeAppPanel:230 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at blurFunction (userCodeAppPanel:230:32)
    at HTMLInputElement.onblur (userCodeAppPanel:1:14867)
blurFunction @ userCodeAppPanel:230
onblur @ userCodeAppPanel:1
```

How to highlight form.html Contact input when there's a duplicate data from Spreadsheet?

Comment: You are not passing any values in onblur="blurFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

Function `blurFunction` is the call back from the `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler`.

Change

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="contact"  onblur="blurFunction()">
```

To

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="contact"  onblur="checkData()">
```

And

```
if (list == result){
```

To

```
if( Number(list) == result ) {
```

Comment: tq! it works now! but still didnt highlighted the duplicate entry

Comment: i've edited my code:
  function blurFunction(values) { //Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771955/2391
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++){
              result = values[i][j];
      console.log(result);
      var list = document.getElementById('contact').value; 

    if (list == result){
        document.getElementById("contact").style.background = "blue";
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById("contact").style.background = "yellow";
    }
          }
  }}

Comment: my console log did shows the array value, but when i keyed in say "5454" it still shows Yellow

Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
VM145:238 contact
VM145:238 5454
VM145:238 1
VM145:238 ererer
VM145:238 45
VM145:238 56
VM145:238 1234
VM145:238 898
VM145:238 09
VM145:238 34
VM145:238 scv

Comment: it works!! thanks so muchh! and I also did remove the else statement
tq again Sir!